# Run IKVM exe as a Windows service

Tags: service, windows-services, ikvm, aot

How could I run my IKVM-compiled exe as a Windows service? Should I write a Wrapper service to it? Is there already anything to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/). It is a service wrapper that eases the burden of creating windows services.